# Job unexpectedly cancelled due to time limit

Tags: time, limit, slurm

There are several partitions on the cluster I work on. With `sinfo` I can see the time limit for each partition. I put my code to work on `mid1` partition which has time limit of `8-00:00:00` from which I understand that time limit is 8 days. I had to wait for `1-15:23:41` which means nearly 1 day and 15 hours. However, my code ran for only `00:02:24` which means  nearly 2.5 minutes (and the solution was converging). Also, I did not set a time limit in the file submitted with `sbatch` The reason of my code stopped was given as:

```
 JOB 3216125 CANCELLED AT 2015-12-19T04:22:04 DUE TO TIME LIMIT
```

So, why my code was stopped if I did not exceed the time limit? I was asking this to the guys who were responsible for the cluster but they did not return.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the value of `DefaultTime` in the output of `scontrol show partitions`. This is the maximum time that is allocated to your job in the case you do not specify it by yourself with `--time`.

Most probably this value is set to 2 minutes to force you to specify a sensible time limit (within the limits of the partition.)